# Happy Music Challenge, Everyone!

Tags: riddle, wordplay, music

> With Seven single steps descending
>   Spirits rise and peer attending.
>   Return with leap then shuffling tread
>   While dirt envelops royal head.
>   Two times the trek from eight to three
>   By steps of one or none shall be.
>   Concurrent with these two down cycles
>   Shall be enlarging ventricles.

I have given here clues to the title and composer as well as the tune and lyrics of the extremely recognizable beginning of a very well known song. Because I have given you almost all of the notes of the first dozen bars, I feel justified in being somewhat obscure on a few of the most distinctive parts. Some basic musical knowledge would certainly help, but there is nothing here, I'm sure, that this group can't handle.

Comment: I had an idea based on the first line but it doesn't really fit much beyond that.

Comment: Yah. I have an idea, I'm not quite 100% but it seems to fit. I'll post when I have a min or if no one else gives it a go soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The song is

> Joy to the World

Seven single steps descending

> The first line of the song descends down a major scale with no repeated notes - 7 steps.

Spirits rise and peer attending

> Spirits rise - Joy, peer attending - the Lord is come?

Return with leap the shuffling tread

> The last line of each verse starts with an octave leap.

While dirt envelops royal head.

> let Earth receive her King

Two times the trek from eight to three 
By steps of one or none shall be.
Concurrent with these two down cycles
Shall be enlarging ventricles.

> That outlines the melody where the words are "Let ev'ry heart prepare Him room", which solves the enlarging ventricles, as well.

Oh and the title

> Happy [Christmas], Everyone!

Credit to my wife, the music teacher. :)

Comment: But it's almost Easter. Not Christmas. XD

Comment: I *knew* you could Handel it. Well done!

Comment: Oddly enough, I couldn't connect the hints to Handel directly. Did I miss something? You said you hinted that the clue mentioned the composer..

Comment: @Z.Dailey - Technically, that *should* be a Second Coming song, not Christmas.  Oh, and it's not known for sure that Handel wrote it.  He's the best guess, but nobody actually knows.  The words were by Isaac Watts.  See [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joy_to_the_World)

Comment: The composer hint is the last word of the explanatory section. I suppose I should have called him the presumed composer but that seemed rather minor to me. A Watts pun almost made it in but sanity prevailed at the last moment.

Comment: The choice of song wasn't seasonal. I just had a hard time coming up with a song that practically everyone knows. Christmas songs seem to be it and this one had some features that I thought lent themselves to a puzzle. Small note for musicians. The leap in the third line refers to the fifth interval that occurs with the words "let earth" as the tune ascends from the tonic back up to the octave. Oddly, this interval gives away the tune more clearly than all the rest of the notes in the first twelve bars.

Comment: The title of the puzzle is "Joy To the Puzzling.se World"